In a Dart Iterator, how can I tell me if there is a current value without using moveNext?
I want to extend the Dart Iterator class with a function that tells me if there is a current value available.
I can't look at the return value of Iterator.moveNext because it has the unwanted side-effect of moving the Iterator forward each time I call it.
I can't check whether Iterator.current is null, because Iterator.current is undefined if there is no value available.
I wanted to extend Iterator to override Iterator.moveNext so that it sets a boolean field (e.g. isActive) whenever it is called, which can then be queried without side-effects, but it's not possible to inherit from Iterable (because it's an interface class) and it's not possible to add any instance fields to an extension of Iterable.
My current workaround is to implement a wrapper for Iterable, but that creates other problems that I really want to avoid.
Any suggestions (short of asking the Dart team to implement something like isActive in the core library)?

You need to keep the contract of Iterator, so whatever limitations you see, that's it.

To me, it is not quite clear what the problem is. Could you not have a class say AwareIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> with a custom moveNext() method that sets a hasCurrent flag?

Thanks Dan, your suggestion is exactly what my current workaround is (as described in my original question above). But the dart core libraries won't return AwareIterator, they still assume Iterator. It also adds an extra indirection for every instance and function call, which will affect performance.

It's trivial to implement yourself:
class HasCurrentIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  final Iterator<T> _source;
  bool _hasCurrent = false;

  HasCurrentIterator(this._source);

  bool get hasCurrent => _hasCurrent;
  bool moveNext() => _hasCurrent = _source.moveNext();
  T get current => _source.current;
}

(Basically what Dan R suggested.)
The odds of that going into the platform libraries are slim-to-none.
It would be a breaking change for all existing iterators.
It's information that you have, implicitly in the code. If you create a new iterator, it does not have a current value. If you have called moveNext, then it has a current value if that call returned true. You should know whether you have called moveNext, because you should know if it returned false.
What problem are you actually trying to solve? Maybe there is a simpler approach.

See my comment to Dan R's suggestion. Actually I question if adding an extra function to Iterator would be a breaking change for the platform libraries . Existing code would simply not use it.

I want to avoid having to declare and use an extra variable when using an iterator . A good example where such an extra variable is unavoidable is in the dart core library (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/join.html)

And lastly the principle of side-effect free programming is very important to me. Dart allows me to do that, but not if I want to use the standard Iterator.

Adding a member to an interface is breaking if there are any existing classes implementing that interface. They would then all no longer have a complete implementation of the interface.

The join method in the core library doesn't have any extra variables, so it's definitely avoidable. It uses moveNext directly in branch conditions, every time. It stores the current value once, because it actually wants to keep that value across an attempt to move forward. That wouldn't be helped by knowing whether there is a current value.

An iterator is inherently mutable state, so side-effect-free programming won't work with it. For that, you would have to define an iterator as type of state and a function that takes that state, and returns a new updated state. That would be nice, but it's not how iterators work. Instead they encapsulate the state and keeps the current state inside the object, overwriting the old state when they update.
The typing of a functional iterator is tricky, because it has an existential type for the state. You don't need to know it, but you hve to pass it back to the update function.

lrn: thanks for your comments, I appreciate them.

You are right, any implementations of the interface would be affected, so it would be a breaking change. Come to think of it, any change whatsover to a core library class interface would be a breaking change.

Interface.join does indeed have a helper variable called first. It's needed to store the first value, since the act of checking if there is a subsequent value changes the result of calling current.

On side-effect free programming and iterators, I expressed myself badly: I meant the principle that functions that return values should be side-effect free, and that only void functions can have side-effects. You are right that iterators inherently have a state; I guess I'm just arguing that moveNext should be a void function, and the job of determining if there is a current value should be left to a separate bool function that doesn't change the state.

That is a design choice, but not the one taken here (or in C# IEnumerator). One could argue that there should be a hasCurrent getter, and I can accept that argument (even if it's unlikely to happen), but I can't see why moveNext is not allowed to return the current value of that getter too, just because it also did mutation. Forcing you to do moveNext() and then always immediately read hasCurrent is not good API usability.

Agree it's a design choice. Actually, it's a methodology choice: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

This answer is a reply to the comment:

the dart core libraries won't return AwareIterator, they still assume
Iterator.

Using the approach suggested by lrn, you could have for example:
extension HasCurrent<E> on Iterable<E> {
  HasCurrentIterator<E> get hasCurrentIterator => HasCurrentIterator(iterator);
}

Usage:
void main(List<String> args) {
  final list = List<int>.generate(1000, (i) => i);
  final it = list.hasCurrentIterator;
  print(it.hasCurrent);
}


Thanks Dan, that's very helpful. I already tried this approach but vscode complained that list.hasCurrentIterator wasn't recognised, which misled me into thinking the approach wouldn't work. I just found out that vscode needed to be reloaded before it would recognise list.HasCurrentIterator. Now it works :)
